# convert insert queries from sql file to php array

Tags: php, mysql, regex, file

I have a sql file which is having lot of insert queries.
is there any way to convert these insert queries to php arrays?

i dont want to insert these items directly to database.
before inserting i want to filter lot of items from these

```
`INSERT INTO `products` (`p_id`, `p_name`, `p_parent`, `p_dependent`,`p_pid`) VALUES
(1, 'some', "some", '2', '1'),(1, 'some', "some", '2', '1'),(1, 'some', "some", '2', '1'),(1, 'some', "some", '2', '1')
```

is there any option in regex to convert these into array?

Answer (score 2):

Take the whole query in a PHP string, then explode it for paranthesis and you will find (after the first return) your query values.
From here, you can further explode them by commas to return each value of the query if you want to avoid some of them.
After having your queries all good in a PHP array, just parse the array and execute insert statements with the values in your array.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function

```
function convert_QueryString_to_array($QueryString) {
    //---get fields-----
    $pos_fields_start=strpos($QueryString,'(')+1;
    $pos_fields_end=strpos($QueryString,')');
    $length=$pos_fields_end-$pos_fields_start;
    $insert=substr($QueryString,$pos_fields_start,$length);
    $fields=explode(",", $insert);

    //---get values----
    $Values=substr($QueryString,$pos_fields_end+1);
    $pos_value_start=strpos($Values,'(')+1;
    $pos_value_end=strpos($Values,')');
    $length=$pos_value_end-$pos_value_start;
    $value=substr($Values,$pos_value_start,$length);
    $fields_value=explode(",", $value);

    //---result------
    $result_array=array();
    for ($i=0;$i<count($fields);$i++ {
        $result_array[$fields[$i]]=$fields_value[$i];
    }
    return $result_array;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please do not post "do this" answers on Stack Overflow.  Your answer will be much more helpful to the asker and future researchers if you include a plain English explanation of how your snippet works and why you feel it is the best approach.  What if a table name, column name, or value contains a parenthesis?  This doesn't strike me as a robust SQL parser.